# Normal products of groups with maximal nilpotency class

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

Let $H$ be a nilpotent group of class $a$ and $K$ a nilpotent group of class $b$. If $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of a group $G$, then we know that $HK$ is a normal nilpotent subgroup of $G$ and $HK$ has class $\leq a+b$.

Can we always find examples where this upper bound is attained? That is: given $a$ and $b$, can we always find groups $H$, $K$ and $G$ such that:

- $H$ is nilpotent of class $a$
- $K$ is nilpotent of class $b$
- $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$, and $HK$ is nilpotent of class $a+b$

I think this is possible when $b = 1$. Let $G = D_{2^{a+2}} = \langle x, y: x^2 = y^{2^{a+1}} = 1, xyx^{-1} = y^{-1} \rangle$ be the dihedral group of order $2^{a+2}$. Let $H = \langle x, y^2 \rangle \cong D_{2^{a+1}}$ and $K = \langle y \rangle$. Then $H$ and $K$ are normal subgroups of $G$, $H$ has class $a$, $K$ has class $1$ and $HK = G$ has class $a+1$.

Comment: If $a=b$ or $a=b+2$, I think a wreath product $D_{2^{(a+b)/2+1}} \wr C_2$ works.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Thanks for the bounty. Constructing examples seems a bit tricky.. is there anything like an "external normal product" of groups? Ie. given groups $H$ and $K$, is there a general way to construct all groups $G = HK$, where $H$ and $K$ are normal in $G$? For example, semidirect products are determined by $H$, $K$ and a homomorphism $H \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(K)$. Is there something like this for normal products?

Comment: I don't know if something like that would even be useful. Just trying to figure out what is the best way to understand the structure of a normal product of two groups.

Comment: Lately I have found normal products fairly surprising. The basic ingredients for the normal product must include an isomorphism between a subgroup of $H$ and a subgroup of $K$, along with homomorphisms from $H$ and $K$ to the automorphism group of that subgroup. When the subgroup is trivial, one gets the direct product.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Do you also need a homomorphism $H \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(K)$ or $K \rightarrow \operatorname{Aut}(H)$ to completely determine the normal product?

Comment: @MikkoKorhonen: I'm working on that right now in between actual job work. Certainly we want to be able to build those homomorphisms, but then there are compatibility conditions galore. I am currently looking into crossed homomorphisms from K to $H\cap K$, and friends.

Comment: Spin, MK, and I all have the same question, so http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/474396/expression-for-normal-product-similar-to-semidirect-product is available to answer it :-)

Answer (score 2):

I made some progress with this. I am virtually certain that the answer is yes, and that I could produce an example for any reasonably sized $a$ and $b$ but I am not confident of being able to prove it.

Fix some $n$ and let $G$ be a Sylow 2-subgroup of $S_{2^n}$. So $G$ is an iterated wreath product of cyclic groups of order 2. The (nilpotency) class of $G$ is $2^{n-1}$. It has $n$ generators, which we can take to be $g_1=(1,2)$, $g_2=(1,3)(2,4)$, $g_3=(1,5)(2,6)(3,7)(4,8)$, $\ldots$,
$g_n=(1,2^{n-1}+1)(2,2^{n-1}+2)\cdots(2^{n-1},2^n)$.

For $1 \le i \le n$, let $H_i$ be the normal closure of $g_i$ in $G$. Then $H_i$ has class $2^{i-2}$ (except that class of $H_1$ is 1). More generally, if $S$ is any subset of $\{1,2,\ldots,n\}$, then the the class of the normal closure in $G$ of $\{g_i : i \in S\}$ is the sum of the classes of $H_i$ for $i \in S$. I am moderately confident that I could prove the above claims if forced!

So, if the binary expansions of $a$ and $b$ have no 1s in the same positions, then we can solve the problem using these normal closures. For example, if $a=11$, $b=20$, then we take $n=6$, and the subgroups $\langle H_2,H_3,H_5 \rangle$, $\langle  H_4,H_6 \rangle$, which have classes 11 and 20, and their product has class 31.

In the general case, I am convinced that we can always solve the problem in a suitable quotient of some such $G$ by a term in its lower central series, and I have had no difficulty doing this for lots of different values of $a,b$, but I am not confident of being able to prove that this is always possible.

Comment: Thanks! I still haven't had time to verify the ideas of the $a \cup b$ construction, but your answer for that one is just fine (my problem; start of teaching semester here).

Comment: I more or less understand what is going on now, without having proven anything formally. If you want to talk more about the details some time then that would fine.

Answer (score 0):

Not always. Take $H,K$ abelian, ${\rm gcd}(|H|,|K|)=1$. Then $H\cap K=1$, so $HK$ is abelian also.

(This is true also for nilpotent groups of coprime orders.)

**Addendum:** This is not complete answer (thank to Jack Schmidt).

Comment: I think he allows $H$ and $K$ to vary (so I would guess the answer is yes or at least close to yes).

Comment: @Jack Schmidt: You are right, thank you.

Comment: @JackSchmidt: Right, that's what I meant. I'll edit to make it more clear